# Mongo Shell No Method Find

Tags: mongodb

I am running Debian with MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3

I run

```
use dbname
db.stats.find()
```

And it outputs the following

```
> db.stats.find()
Mon May 13 17:55:20.933 JavaScript execution failed: TypeError: Object function (scale){
return this.runCommand( { dbstats : 1 , scale : scale } );
} has no method 'find'
```

However running it on other collections works fine.

This mongo instance is being used with nodejs.

Comment: do you have a collection named "stats"?  Since stats is a method on db object, you would get this error if you tried to use regular shell syntax.  Does show collections show this collection in this db?

Answer (score 8):

If you really created a collection named stats in your database dbname then I would advise you to rename it.  In the shell the db object has a stats() method for looking at statistics of the database.

Meanwhile you can use slightly more complex syntax:

```
> db.getSiblingDB("dbname").getCollection("stats").find()
Fetched 0 record(s) in 4ms
```

Or if you are in dbname then:

```
> db.getCollection("stats").find()
```

Comment: That is why then , I didn't realise stats was predefined.

Comment: How can I rename if db.stats.rename('blcstats')
Mon May 13 23:05:33.990 JavaScript execution failed: TypeError: Object function (scale){
return this.runCommand( { dbstats : 1 , scale : scale } );
} has no method 'rename'

Comment: use the same syntax I showed:  db.getCollection("stats").renameCollection("newname");

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want `db.stats()`.

Comment: I don't think so http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/